# Troubles deploying Nodejs API with Hapi on Azure and Repl.it

Tags: node.js, azure, hapi, replit

I'm using Hapi to run an API testing deployment on different platforms. 
First of all I tried Heroku and everything worked fine. 
Then I tried to run on Azure Web Apps and it failed with an error
"Hello all.

I'm using Hapi to run an API testing deployment on different platforms. 
First of all I tried Heroku and everything worked fine. 
Then I tried to run on Azure Web Apps and it failed with an error that error:

[image]

First I thought it was some error particular to Azure, but now I'm trying to run on Repl.it and got caught with the same error. 
Is it specific to Hapi? 
I'm using Yarn to manage my dependencies.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when I tried to test Hapi on my cloud container before.

For my case, there has compatibility issue between Hapi version (I used v19.1.1) and Node version (my server default version 10.16.0).

The issue is resolved after I upgrade the Node version to **12.16.1 LTS**.